# How to express "with at least one component"

Tags: regex

I trying to check string data using regular expression.
form of input data are as bellow.

```
#1X2Y3Z@4A5B6C (valid)
<--nothing (valid)
#1X2Y3Z (valid)
#@4A (valid)

#4A@ (invalid)
```

`@` must be followed by at least one component matching `([0-9]+)A`, `([0-9]+)B` or `([0-9]+)C`

And `#` must be the first character if input is not an empty string.

I wrote this regex:

```
#(([0-9]+)X)?(([0-9]+)Y)?(([0-9]+)Z)?@(([0-9]+)A)?(([0-9]+)B)?([0-9]+)C)?
```

but it regards `#1X2Y3Z@` as valid.

Comment: You mean this `^@[ABC]+$` ?

Comment: What do you want to check exactly ? and what language you are using?

Comment: thank you for your help, I want to check if @ is represented with at least one component {A,B,C} or more. so "A", "AC", "@" are invalid, "@A", "@AC" are valid and empty string is also valid. and I'm using std:regex

Comment: This is correct:  `^(#(?:[0-9][A-Z])*@?(?:[0-9][A-Z])+?)?$`

Comment: @joejo: I edited your question to make it easier to read.  Please check and make sure I got the meaning right.

Answer (score 1):

> @ must be represented with at least one component {A,B,C} or more and empty string is also valid.

```
^(?:@[ABC]+)?$
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times, so `[ABC]+` matches one or more A or B or C. `^` called starting anchor and `$` called end of the line anchor.

**Update:**

```
^(?:#(?:@?[0-9]+[ABCXYZ])+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dW8mK5/2)

Comment: Thank you for reply. and its exactly right, but  if I change A, B, C  to ([0-9]A)?, ([0-9]B)?, ([0-9]C)?, it's not work. in this case, how to resolve it?

Comment: Where the digits came from? Add anchors `^([0-9]A)?$`, so that it would allow empty strings or digit A like `5A`.

Comment: I've modified my Question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
^(#(?:[0-9][A-Z])*@?(?:[0-9]|[A-Z])+)?$
```

I tested it with your requirements as per description:

> @ must be represented with at least one component [([0-9]+)A([0-9]+)B, ([0-9]+)C].
>
> And # must be exist in front of string if input is not empty string.

Comment: As I understand it, the `@` is optional, but if it's there it *must* be followed by some more characters.  Your regex doesn't say that.

Comment: thank yous julianG, it works, but as I think, it's useful only when  search, not match. for example, let input string "#9A5B@5", your regex can search #9A5B but It can not show whether input is valid or not.

Comment: Try this one: `^(#(?:[0-9][A-Z])*@?(?:[0-9]|[A-Z])+)?$`